# Fedora: NO module named RPM when using YUM

Tags: python, fedora, rpm, python-2.6, yum

I removed numpy and scipy contents from the system's Python 2.6.4 in order to install different versions for them and now I broke YUM. The error I get is the following:

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named rpm

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

    It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
    current version of Python, which is:
    2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jun  4 2010, 18:20:31) 
    [GCC 4.4.4 20100503 (Red Hat 4.4.4-2)]

    If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
    the yum faq at:
      http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

Also when I import YUM from inside the python console I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>

import rpm ImportError:

 No module named rpm
```

Python is working fine and I managed to install numpy however I want to install scipy using YUM and I can't. Also when I run:

```
rpm --version
```

I get: RPM version 4.8.1.

Is there a way to solve this issue? I would be grateful for any advice or pointers towards solving this issue.

Comment: Not sure how to fix your problem, but once you have it sorted out you should use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and leave your base Python installation alone. Virtualenv makes it easy to create isolated Python environments and management thereof, and you can play around without disturbing the main installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `rpm-python` installed. If yum was previously working, then it is difficult to see how the rpm module is not installed. Take a look in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm` - that directory should exist, and should contain a couple of python files (`__init__.py` and `transaction.py`) and a shared library for rpm.

If the `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm` directory or the files are missing then you could try to install it. First check whether it is in the RPM database using `rpm -q rpm-python`. If it not installed then you can get the rpm from somewhere like [this mirror](http://mirror.as24220.net/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/r/rpm-python-4.11.1-7.fc20.i686.rpm) and install it (`rpm -ivh http://mirror.as24220.net/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/r/rpm-python-4.11.1-7.fc20.i686.rpm`). You will need to find the correct version for your Fedora and machine architecture.

More likely it will be (apparently) installed, in which case you could try force a reinstallation. Just be certain that you have access to the correct rpm of the same identical version, download it to be sure. If you are confident, then install with `rpm -ivh --force rpm_file`.

Then run python and see if you can import rpm and import yum.

Comment: Thank you mhawke this solved my initial problem. After importing yum I got a new error about pycurl and I was able to solve it following the same procedure you mention (i.e. finding the rpm that was already installed and reinstalling it). Then importing yum lead to another error about the yum-metadata-parser which I solved again by reinstalling the already existing rpm which finally enabled me to use yum again!