# syntax error near unexpected token `LIBCONFIGXX,' in PKG_CHECK_MODULES

Tags: linux, centos, makefile, configure

I am trying to compile [slurm](https://github.com/0xception/slurm) to modify squid's http response & insert content (eg. image/script) via e-cap interface.

But I am facing some issues while running the `./configure`

The **README** says:
to build the ecap slurm adapter.

```
% ./bootstrap.sh
% ./configure
% make
% sudo make install
```

after executing `./bootstrap.sh` & then `./configure` i get an error as below:

```
./configure && make
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
remembering installation prefix as /usr/local
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether the C++ compiler (g++) is a C++ compiler... yes
enforcing -O1 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether custom g++ flags work... probably
changing g++ flags to -g -O1 -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -pipe
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lecap... yes
./configure: line 17474: syntax error near unexpected token `LIBCONFIGXX,'
./configure: line 17474: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBCONFIGXX, libconfig++ >= 1.4,,'
```

At line 17474, configure has:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBCONFIGXX, libconfig++ >= 1.4,,
    as_fn_error $? "libconfig++ 1.4 or newer not found." "$LINENO" 5
)
```

My system setup:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

pkg-config --version
0.27.1

locate libconfig
/usr/lib64/libconfig++.so.9
/usr/lib64/libconfig++.so.9.1.3
/usr/lib64/libconfig.so.9
/usr/lib64/libconfig.so.9.1.3
```

I've tried searching a lot for the issue, but couldn't get it resolved. Also It'll be helpful if I get few names of library tools which modify the squids response to insert an image (either free/paid)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install libconfig-devel package?

Comment: Hi, I did not install it explicitly,but when I checked the `/usr/lib64/libconfig++.so.9.1.3` as mentioned in post, I presumed its already installed by default on my CentOS. Should I reinstall it?Besides i already did yum install libconfig-devel,but getting an error: `yum install libconfig-devel
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named rpm`

Comment: You also need the libconfig++.pc file, which is part of libconfig-devel.

Comment: It looks like you broke your yum installation. Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300661/fedora-no-module-named-rpm-when-using-yum